# Why is chosen preventing a JavaScript conditional from working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

There are two snippets below. I'm using Bootstrap 3 and Chosen for my `select` menus.

The functionality with the following is that when a specific selection is made (i.e.; Social Services), then a second `select` menu displays. That menu goes away if Defendant, Minor or Witness are selected. The piece that controls this is here:

```
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("change", function () {
  var style = this.value == 4 || this.value == 5 ? "block" : "none";
  document.getElementById("form2").style.display = style;
});
```

Snippet 1: I am able to use chosen, but when I select **Social Services**, the second select menu doesn't come up. In order for chosen to work, the chosen class must be set to a `width: 100%;`, which is this piece:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  width: "100%"
});
```

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  width: "100%"
});

document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("change", function () {
  var style = this.value == 4 || this.value == 5 ? "block" : "none";
  document.getElementById("form2").style.display = style;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-chosen@1.4.2/bootstrap-chosen.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-sm-6 b-r">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form1">Involved How?</label>
        <select id="form1" name="form1" data-placeholder="Involved as..." class="chosen-select form-control">
          <option value="1">Defendant</option>
          <option value="2">Minor</option>
          <option value="3">Witness</option>
          <option value="4">Social Services</option>
          <option value="5">Prosecution</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 b-r">
      <div class="form-group" id="form2" style="display: none;">
        <label for="form2">Agency</label>
        <select name="form2" class="form-control chosen-select">
          <option value="1">Legal Services</option>
          <option value="2">Social Services</option>
          <option value="3">Prosecutor's Office</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Snippet 2: If I remove the snippet:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  width: "100%"
});
```

...then the select menu turns back into it's native format (without chosen) and allows me to choose **Social Services** and display the second select menu, but the chosen functionality doesn't work in that first select menu.

```js
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("change", function () {
  var style = this.value == 4 || this.value == 5 ? "block" : "none";
  document.getElementById("form2").style.display = style;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-chosen@1.4.2/bootstrap-chosen.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-sm-6 b-r">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form1">Involved How?</label>
        <select id="form1" name="form1" data-placeholder="Involved as..." class="chosen-select form-control">
          <option value="1">Defendant</option>
          <option value="2">Minor</option>
          <option value="3">Witness</option>
          <option value="4">Social Services</option>
          <option value="5">Prosecution</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 b-r">
      <div class="form-group" id="form2" style="display: none;">
        <label for="form2">Agency</label>
        <select name="form2" class="form-control chosen-select">
          <option value="1">Legal Services</option>
          <option value="2">Social Services</option>
          <option value="3">Prosecutor's Office</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only difference here is this:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  width: "100%"
});
```

**Does anyone know why this is happening or if there is a workaround for it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because Chosen raises jQuery-based events, so using `addEventListener()` won't detect them. You need to use jQuery's `on()` method instead:

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  width: "100%"
});

$("#form1").on("change", function() {
  $("#form2").toggle(this.value == 4 || this.value == 5);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-chosen@1.4.2/bootstrap-chosen.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-sm-6 b-r">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form1">Involved How?</label>
        <select id="form1" name="form1" data-placeholder="Involved as..." class="chosen-select form-control">
          <option value="1">Defendant</option>
          <option value="2">Minor</option>
          <option value="3">Witness</option>
          <option value="4">Social Services</option>
          <option value="5">Prosecution</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 b-r">
      <div class="form-group" id="form2" style="display: none;">
        <label for="form2">Agency</label>
        <select name="form2" class="form-control chosen-select">
          <option value="1">Legal Services</option>
          <option value="2">Social Services</option>
          <option value="3">Prosecutor's Office</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```